# Как отключить xss фильтрацию для контроллера asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xss, asp.net-mvc, .net

Здравствуйте. Пишу админку для сайта, и там при добавлении статьи должна быть отключена xss фильтрация, иначе выскакивает ошибка. Как отключить для этого действия или контроллера xss фильтрацию?

Comment: Если кому-то интересно, то ответ я нашел здесь: http://hashcode.ru/questions/132615/asp-net-asp-mvc-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8. ответ к этому вопросу не сработал, но я его принимаю из-за отсутствия других.

Comment: Свой ответ перенёс сюда, ибо здесь ему и место :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам должен помочь атрибут [`ValidateInputAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx). Его можно повесить на  отдельные методы контроллера (`actions`), либо сразу на весь контроллер. Конструктор прнимает один параметр - `enableValidation`. Думаю, смысл ясен.
Однако, в `ASP.NET` версии 4 и выше, для корректной работы этого атрибута необходимо в Web.config'е изменить режим валидации запросов:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Это нужно сделать, потому что в режиме "4.0" валидация запроса происходит ещё до фазы "`BeginRequest`" `HTTP`-запроса. Поэтому валидация начнется до того, как отработает атрибут `ValidateInputAttribute`. Режим "2.0" вернёт корректное поведение.

Answer (score 2):

Извиняюсь, может я неправильно понял вопрос и ваш комментарий по поводу того, что сработало, а что нет, но не этот ли атрибут вам нужен? [ValidateInput(false)]

Comment: Да, именно.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого поля в моделе попробуй указать тип не `string`, a `HtmlString`.

Comment: А между прочим не работает